# how to use react dropzone uploader with react bootstrap Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I want to use `react-dropzone-uploader` in my react js project with custom input. when I use the code as is from the example documentation, it works fine.. but if I tried to change the component from `label` into `Button`, when I click on the button it doesn't show the file explorer even though there's no error in the page and developer tools.

here's my [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-chihiro-irc0nu?file=/src/App.js:0-247)

**App.js**

```js
import "./styles.css";
import DzInput from "./DzInput";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello Dropzone</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <DzInput />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**DzInput.js**

```js
import { getDroppedOrSelectedFiles } from "html5-file-selector";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone-uploader";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const DzInput = () => {
  const Input = ({ accept, onFiles, files, getFilesFromEvent }) => {
    const text = files.length > 0 ? "Add more files" : "Choose files";

    return (
      <label // if I change this into <Button then it doesn't work anymore
        variant="primary"
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#007bff",
          color: "#fff",
          cursor: "pointer",
          padding: 15,
          borderRadius: 3
        }}
      >
        {text}
        <input
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          type="file"
          accept={accept}
          multiple
          onChange={(e) => {
            getFilesFromEvent(e).then((chosenFiles) => {
              onFiles(chosenFiles);
            });
          }}
        />
      </label>
    );
  };

  const CustomInput = () => {
    const handleSubmit = (files, allFiles) => {
      console.log(
        "handlesubmit",
        files.map((f) => f.meta)
      );
      allFiles.forEach((f) => f.remove());
    };

    const getFilesFromEvent = (e) => {
      console.log("getfilesfromevent");
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        getDroppedOrSelectedFiles(e).then((chosenFiles) => {
          resolve(chosenFiles.map((f) => f.fileObject));
        });
      });
    };

    return (
      <Dropzone
        accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*,.pdf"
        getUploadParams={() => ({ url: "https://httpbin.org/post" })}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        InputComponent={Input}
        getFilesFromEvent={getFilesFromEvent}
      />
    );
  };

  return <CustomInput />;
};

export default DzInput;
```